# Unexpected vertical gap in a table cell

Tags: hyphenation, tabularx

while I'm trying to make a table, I found an unexpected gap in the leftmost cell in a table.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm} *{13}{|Y}|}%{|X|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x|x| }

    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|c|}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0pt} Wavelength & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & \#4 & \#5 & \#6 & \#7 & \#8 & \#9 & \#10 & \#11 & \#12 \\   \hline
    400 &   0.0025  &   0.0043  &   0.0020  &   0.0008  &   0.0050  &   0.0036  &   0.0063  &   0.0010  &   0.0014  &   0.0040  &   0.0057  &   0.0014  
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the result.

[image: code result]

How can I remove the vertical gap in a cell 'Wavelength'?

Please help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Just remove the space between `\hspace{0pt}` and `Wavelength`, i.e., write `\hspace{0pt}Wavelength`. (The extra, unwanted row is created because the column is just narrow enough to prevent LaTeX from placing both the space and the fragment "Wave'" on the same line.)

Comment: @Mico Why is the `\hspace{0pt}` necessary to get the hyphenation to work?

Comment: @Mico It worked perfectly! Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: @A.Ellett - The directive `\hspace{0pt}` is needed to allow hyphenation of "Wavelength" *if* the TeX engine being used is *not* LuaTeX. (LuaTeX permits hyphenation of the first word in a paragraph; all other engines do not.) For TeX, each table cell is a "paragraph". The directive `\hspace{0pt}` inserts discardable whitespace (of zero width, naturally); thus, the word "Wavelength" no longer is the first word in the (logical) "paragraph", and hyphenation is permitted.

Comment: @Mico Sounds like an answer to me (unless you feel we should dupe to the 'where is `%` required' question).

Comment: @JosephWright I've gone ahead and posted an answer, as the table (as posted by the OP) has additional issues besides the spurious blank row.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the major issue you've indentified, there are two further (and minor) issues that should also be fixed.

- The major issue is, of course, the spurious blank line above the hyphenated word "Wave-length". It arises because (a) there's a space between `\hspace{0pt}` and the word "Wavelength" and (b) the column is just narrow enough to permit "Wave-" but not " Wave-" (note the space at the start of the string) to fit. Because the initial " " doesn't fit, LaTeX has to create three rows to make the entire string " Wavelength" fit.

  The best "fix"  is not to have the space between `\hspace{0pt}` and `Wavelength` in the first place, i.e., to write the cell's contents as

  ```
  \hspace{0pt}Wavelength
  ```

  Remark: If the first column were just a bit wider -- say, 1.1cm instead of 1.0cm -- you wouldn't have noticed this issue at all, because " Wave-" (with the leading space) would happen to fit. (You might have then been forced to puzzle, though, over why "Wave-" didn't seem to be centered properly above "length".)
- If you look closely at the screenshot you posted, you'll notice that the numbers in the 12 data columns aren't perfectly centered -- even though `\centering` is in effect. What's going on? The less-than-perfect centering is happening because the columns aren't quite enough. The *total* width of column consists of the usable width plus whitespace in the amount of `\tabcolsep` on either side. LaTeX won't let the cell contents encroach on the left-hand whitespace; if the cell contents can't be hyphenated, they must protrude into the right-hand whitespace.

  How to fix this? The default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`. Reduce the paramter's value to, say, `3pt`, and proper centering becomes feasible.
- Finally, in your example code the second argument of `tabularx` specifies 13 columns of type `Y` even though only 12 such columns are needed. While this doesn't affect the typeset output, it does generate lots of warning messages about "overfull \hbox"es. It's usually a good idea to eliminate the source of warning messages -- in this case by specifying

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering}m{1cm} *{12}{|Y}|}
  ```

  as the header of the `tabularx` environment.

The following screenshot provides before-and-after comparison. Note both the disappearance of the spurious row as well as the proper centering of the contents of columns 2 thru 13 in the table labelled "After". The third table in the screenshot, incidentally, shows what the table would look like if you (a) got rid of all vertical lines and (b) used the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`. I hope you'll agree that the resulting "open" look of the table is aesthetically pleasing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,caption,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]  % "[h!]" used just for this example
  \caption{Before}
  \centering 
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm} *{13}{|Y}|}

    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|c|}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0pt} Wavelength & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & \#4 & \#5 & \#6 & \#7 & \#8 & \#9 & \#10 & \#11 & \#12 \\   \hline
    400 & 0.0025  & 0.0043  & 0.0020  & 0.0008  & 0.0050  & 0.0036  & 0.0063  & 0.0010  & 0.0014  & 0.0040  & 0.0057  & 0.0014 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{After}
  %%\centering  % not needed, since width of "tabularx" equals width of text block
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm} *{12}{|Y}|}

    \hline
    \multicolumn{13}{|c|}{Team sheet} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0pt}Wavelength & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & \#4 & \#5 & \#6 & \#7 & \#8 & \#9 & \#10 & \#11 & \#12 \\   \hline
    400 & 0.0025  & 0.0043  & 0.0020  & 0.0008  & 0.0050  & 0.0036  & 0.0063  & 0.0010  & 0.0014  & 0.0040  & 0.0057  & 0.0014 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \caption{With booktabs-based rules}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
  %%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1cm} *{12}{Y} @{}}

    \toprule
    \hspace{0pt}Wavelength & \multicolumn{12}{c@{}}{Team sheet} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-13}
     & \#1 & \#2 & \#3 & \#4 & \#5 & \#6 & \#7 & \#8 & \#9 & \#10 & \#11 & \#12 \\   \midrule
    400 & 0.0025  & 0.0043  & 0.0020  & 0.0008  & 0.0050  & 0.0036  & 0.0063  & 0.0010  & 0.0014  & 0.0040  & 0.0057  & 0.0014 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```